# Three way (model) relationship

Tags: php, foreign-keys, relationship, laravel, eloquent

I have the following [Schema and Model](http://paste.laravel.com/mwT) setup, with this [seed data](http://paste.laravel.com/mDi).

My goal is to achieve a three-way-relationship, it may be a wrong term, but at last, that's what I'm calling it.

Three-way as in:

- Cheques have Tokens attached
- Attached Tokens have Values attached which are aware of Cheque->Token attachment.

The problem is with the relationship from `Token` to `Value`, where, when I load `Values`, they do not take in mind the associated `Cheque` hence, returning all values that belong to a `Token`.

I do not know whether the `Value` Schema is correct for this three-way-relationship, hence, I also doubt the `Value` model relationships belonging to `Cheque` and `Token` being correct.

This is how I am currently requesting the models (excerpt from setup):

```
Route::get('test', function()
{
    $cheque = Cheq_Node::with(array('tokens' => function($query) {
        $query->where_sortable(1);
    }, 'tokens.values'))->first();

    dd( $cheques );
});
```

---

I have tried changing `Token` values reference to:

```
public function values()
{
    return $this->has_many('Cheq_Value', 'token_id')->where_node_id($this->pivot->id);
}
```

But that produced me:

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

Adding a `Log::dump( dump($this) )` before the return, shows no Model loaded, just an empty Eloquent model:

```
object(Cheq_Token)[63]
  public 'attributes' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'original' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'relationships' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'exists' => boolean false
  public 'includes' => 
    array (size=1)
      'values' => null
```

No wonder the error is produced there.

How do I make this three-way relationship happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with a different [Schema](http://paste.laravel.com/mOg), and different [Models](http://paste.laravel.com/mOj).

That also required to take a different path for insertion, resulting in the following [test seed](http://paste.laravel.com/mOl).

Retrieving it all with:

```
$nodes = Node::with(array('tokenlinks', 'tokenlinks.token', 'tokenlinks.values'))->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to review your database schema, using appropiate foreign keys in order to retrieve the correct data. Assuming that you would get the result that you want, is not always the best way.

The use of joins in your database will do the trick...